# Integrating a rational function of exponentials

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Let $\gamma ,\mu > 0$ be positive real constants and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ be a real constant. How can I evaluate the following indefinite integral?

$$ \int \frac{e^{2\gamma t} (e^{-\mu t} - e^{2\gamma t})}{\beta  e^{4 \gamma  t}-3 e^{2 \gamma  t}+6 e^{\gamma  t}-4} \mathrm{d}t $$

If we were dealing only with $e^{\gamma  t}$ terms, we could proceed quite easily by substitution ($u = e^{\gamma t}$), but that strategy seems to be foiled by the presence of the $e^{-\mu t}$ term.

Comment: $e^{-\mu t} = (e^{\gamma t})^{-\mu/\gamma}$. Why exactly does u substitution fail?

Comment: @WSL Sure, you can perform the substitution, but have you got an idea how to evaluate the resulting integral (with $u$ raised to a real exponent)?